# White Space below ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout

When I open my Activity on a 16:9 Phone, the Toolbar + the ListView take all of the space so thats fine.

But when I open it on a 19:9 Phone, I get a white space below my ListView (maby 1/5 of the Screen).

This white space doesn't come from the constraint layout, because its white and the constraint layout has a green background color.

(XML of my activity below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mainListView"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background7"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        tools:context=".listview.MainActivity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background7"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />
```

Comment: unfortunately this resulted in the whole listView turning white... After removing      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar", the listView appeared again but now the Toolbar went invisible.

Comment: Same problem... the ListView turns completly white.
Maby it has something to do with the library im using:'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2' 

Btw thanks for your effort trying to help me!